# (Access) Sql Statement Using 3 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, relational-database, inner-join

this is my first time on StackOverflow and I am learning SQL but having trouble with joins, etc. I have a challenge for you today.

Alright Here are the tables:

```
STUDENT
Student_ID Instructor_ID Adviser_ID
2          9723          9945
7          9723          9723
8          9801          9945
17         9945          9945
19         9624          9945
21         9723          9723

INSTRUCTOR
Instructor_ID Person_ID
9624          14
9723          15
9801          11
9945          16

PERSON
Person_ID  Person_First_Name  Person_Last_Name
1          Jim                Johnson
2          John               Doe
...
11         Chuck              John
...
14         Joanne             Jackson
15         Steven             Pruck
16         Scott              Buttermilk
... (Possibly More Records)
```

The SQL query I am trying to get is the Name of each Student's Instructor and the Instructor that is their Adviser. Here is the format:

```
Student_ID | Instructor's First and Last Name | Adviser's First and Last Name
```

Also note that the advisor_ID is the same as the instructor_ID. Here is what I have come up with so far, but going any further I assume I need two inner joins or some subquery:

```
SELECT STUDENT.Student_ID, Person.person_first_name + " " + Person.person_last_name AS Instructor
FROM STUDENT AS S, PERSON AS P, INSTRUCTOR AS I
WHERE S.Instructor_ID = I.Instructor_ID
AND I.person_ID = P.person_ID
ORDER BY S.Student_ID;
```

EDIT: This is for a Microsoft Access Database (Just in case)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `INSTRUCTOR` table?  It appears that the relation between students and instructors is already being handled within the `STUDENT` table.

Comment: The instructor Table is used to find the Person_ID, which you need in order to find the Person's name in the Person table.

Comment: Still looking for the correct answer, as I don't believe these are working for me.

Comment: I think the problem is your schema, which is not normalized.  The `INSTRUCTOR` table is redundant from what I can tell and you can do without it.  The answers are trying to use what you gave us.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 SELECT S.Student_ID, P.person_first_name + " " + P.person_last_name AS Instructor, P1.person_first_name + " " + P1.person_last_name AS Adviser
    FROM STUDENT AS S, 
    inner join INSTRUCTOR AS I on S.Instructor_ID = I.Instructor_ID
    inner join PERSON AS P on I.person_ID = P.person_ID
    inner join INSTRUCTOR AS I1 on S.Adviser_ID = I1.Instructor_ID
    inner join PERSON AS P1 on I1.person_ID = P1.person_ID
ORDER BY S.Student_ID;
```

Comment: Didn't know you can pull from the same table multiple times and call it something else. This helped me the most even though I couldn't get your query to work on my end.

Comment: @JimJohnson You want display adviser so adviser join second table. if it is same table not display result .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUDENT.Student_ID, Person.person_first_name + " " + Person.person_last_name AS Instructor , P.person_first_name + " " + P.person_last_name AS Adviser
FROM STUDENT AS S 
JOIN INSTRUCTOR AS I ON I.Instructor_ID = S.Instructor_ID
JOIN PERSON AS P ON P.Person_ID = I.Person.ID
ORDER BY S.Student_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses two lookups for the two `student` fields (`instructor_id` and `adviser_id`):

```
select student_id,
    (select concat(person_first_name, ' ', person_last_name)
     from instructor i
         inner join person p on i.person_id=p.person_id
     where i.instructor_id=student.instructor_id) instructor,
    (select concat(person_first_name, ' ', person_last_name)
     from instructor i
         inner join person p on i.person_id=p.person_id
     where i.instructor_id=student.adviser_id) advisor
from student
```

You can see it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13b07e/3

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got to eventually work:

```
SELECT S.Student_id, P.person_first_name+" "+P.person_last_name AS Instructor, P1.person_first_name+" "+P1.person_last_name AS Adviser

FROM Student AS S, PERSON AS P, Instructor AS I, Person AS P1, Instructor AS I1
WHERE S.Instructor_ID = I.Instructor_ID 
AND I.person_ID = P.person_ID
AND S.Adviser_ID = I1.Instructor_ID
AND I1.person_ID = P1.person_ID
ORDER BY S.Student_id;
```